# Posting an Achievement in Facebook using As3 API

Tags: facebook, facebook-as3-api

I have registered an achievement for my game in Facebook. But could you please help me to sort out how to post that achievement of Facebook using AS3 API?

Is it just like

```
var wallPostParams:Object ={
achievement :"achievemt url",
access_token :"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

Facebook.postData('me/achievements/', postToWallCompleteHandler, wallPostParams);
```

Is this way to post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var method:String = facebookSession.uid+"/achievements"
var wallPostParams:Object ={
achievement :"achievemt url",
access_token :"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

Facebook.postData(method, postToWallCompleteHandler, wallPostParams);
```

In brief, just replace the "me" by the user Id

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Achievements Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/) Facebook provides to get your achievement working. You first have to register the achievement with your app, and then post the achievements using `/{user_id}/achievements`. You will need to ask the user for the `publish_actions` permission.

You will get errors if the achievement isn't registered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have already registered my achievement successfully, and made a post successfull using graph api explorer. but the problem is, im using as3 facebook api for my game and i try to post my achievment using the above code it says wallpost was unsuccessful.